# dpkg error processing package

Tags: dpkg, linux-headers

I am having an error installing PIP3 using the sudo apt install python3-pip command

I am receiving the below errors. Could anyone please assist?

Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-29 (4.15.0-29.31) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-29 (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29/tools/testing/nvdimm/test/Kbuild.dpkg-tmp': Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-29
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)